# Entity Framework 5 - Deleting Child Records

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

VS 2012 (11.0.60315.01 Update 2), C# 5, Entity Framework 5.0.0.0 (Runtime v4.0.30319)

I know similar questions have been posted in the past, but there does not seem to be an answer.  I think I understand the error, but I'm more interested in finding the 'desired' solution.  **All I want to do is delete a record from the Child table.**  Can anyone help?

This is a **full** and **simple** example.  The **SaveChanges()** throws the following exception:

"The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted."

The code looks like this:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace EFDeleteTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (EFTestEntities context = new EFTestEntities())
            {
                var parent = context.Parents.Single(p => p.Id == 1);

                var child = parent.Children.Single(c => c.Id == 1);

                parent.Children.Remove(child);

                context.SaveChanges(); // Throws the above Exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Database looks like this:

```
Parent
    Id   (PK, int, not null)   IDENTITY
    Name (nvarchar(50), null)

Child
    Id       (PK, int, not null)  IDENTITY
    ParentId (FK, int, not null)  -- Foreign Key to the Parent Table (Id column))
    Name     (nvarchar(50), null)
```

There is one record in the Parent table (Id = 1) and there are 2 records in the Child table (Id's 1 and 2).  Both of the Child records have a ParentId = 1.

Comment: You should include more tags in your question, such as `C#`, `VS2012` tags etc. You will get more views and responses that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you want is to delete the child object, the parent object should not be concerned in the logic. Try the code below, let me know what happens (Not tested).

```
using System.Linq;

namespace EFDeleteTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (EFTestEntities context = new EFTestEntities())
            {                      
                var child = context.Children.Single(c => c.Id == 1);

                context.Children.Remove(child);

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Komenge, You code worked.  My main project (no access to it at the moment) is probably a little more complicated than this example, but I'm sure that I can adjust it to work in a similar way.  Thank you for your quick response.